# Simple query string ignoring fields

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm trying to create a search that returns result based on either a name or a number. My mapping properties look like this.

```
"properties": {
    "id": {
        "type": "integer"
    },
    "img": {
        "type": "binary"
    },
    "name": {
        "type": "string"
    }
}
```

The query I have made is a [simple query string query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-simple-query-string-query.html) and looks like this:

```
{
    "query": {
        "simple_query_string": {
            "query": "test~5",
            "analyzer": "snowball",
            "fields": ["name", "id"],
            "default_operator": "and",
            "lenient": true
        }
    }
}
```

This works perfectly fine for queries that only use data from the `name` field. When I query for `"1488"`, for example, it should return the item with `id == 1488`, but instead it doesn't return anything.

At first I thought `lenient` was missing, but that doesn't solve the problem.

What do I need to look at for my query to work?

**-[EDIT]-**

Thought that maybe ES is only searching the first field. So I changed the query to using `"fields": ["id", "name"]`. This still works when looking for strings, but still no result when looking for a number.

Comment: I am not able to reproduce the problem. You are not doing it like `1488~5`, right? also could you specify ES version?

Comment: No, when looking for a number the query is just "1488".

Comment: Type of id is Integer. I guess,for query String to work the field should be String and analysed which is the case with name field. That's why it is working for name.Adding lenient just ignores exception that occur due to format failures.